# I want to add a timestamp using apps script, but it doesn't work when I paste multiple rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, google-sheets-formula

The code works when one row is edited at a time. But I need to copy and paste multiple rows as well, and the timestamp only appears on the first row (where I paste it).

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var range = e.range;
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var row = range.getRow();  

  var activeSheetName = 'Analysis';

  var statusColumnNum = 17;
  var updateColumnNum = 15;

  if(sheetName == activeSheetName)
  {
    if(spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,statusColumnNum).getValues() == 'No Further Action' || spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,statusColumnNum).getValues() == 'Invalid Code' || spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,statusColumnNum).getValues() == 'For BAF Filing'){
      if(spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,updateColumnNum).getValue() == ''){
        var new_date = new Date();
        spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,updateColumnNum).setValue(new_date).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss A/P");
      }
    }
    else{
      spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,updateColumnNum).setValue('');
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: You can use the event object to determine the entire range that is being change.  Look at e.range.rowStart,columnStart,rowEnd,columnEnd

Answer (score 0):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var spreadSheet = e.source;
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var activeSheetName = 'Analysis';
  var statusColumnNum = 17;
  var updateColumnNum = 15;
  var texts = ['No Further Action', 'Invalid Code', 'For BAF Filing'];
  if (sheetName == activeSheetName) {
    var range = sheet.getRange(range.rowStart, statusColumnNum, range.rowEnd - range.rowStart + 1);
    var values = range.getValues();
    var new_date = new Date();
    range.offset(0, updateColumnNum - statusColumnNum)
      .setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss A/P")
      .setValues(values.map(([q]) => [texts.includes(q) ? new_date : null]));
  }
}
```

- In this case, when this script is run by copying and pasting the values, all edited rows are checked. By this, the date is inserted into your expected rows.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! It is working great. :D

Comment: @Bonnie About `Thank you for taking the time! It is working great.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer